# How can I tint a detailed image with a color in Appcelerator?

Tags: android, ios, appcelerator, image-manipulation, appcelerator-hyperloop

I'm looking for a cross platform method to tint a detailed PNG or JPG, with a color. An example use case would be like this: https://i5.walmartimages.com/asr/74cb7e15-a285-40cc-a294-c157ed6fa8b2_1.b9ab5eb83cad0a612996470fbe7917c3.jpeg?odnHeight=450&odnWidth=450&odnBg=FFFFFF

The above is an image of a model wearing a white shirt.

I would "cut out" the white shirt and overlay it on the model. That gives me a white shirt to manipulate, while the model remains unchanged.

The user would slide their finger on a color chart or something similar. While they're doing this, the shirt would tint with the user's selected color, while also keeping the shadow details. So if they picked a red, the shirt would be red with red shadows.

With all the apps out there that allow you to adjust skin tone, adjust eye color, apply makeup, etc., I'm hoping there's a way to do this with Appcelerator. Many thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 1):

I did this in an older app to change the color of knitted hats and fingernails for demo purposes. For the hats we took images and removed the color (but keeping the shadow and lighting) and all color parts are transparent. I can only show you the demo nails:

[image]

You put a normal colored view behind this transparent PNG and change the color of the view. Don't need to tint the objects. It's quicker and saves power/memory.

Comment: That's very interesting. How did you make the image transparent while keeping the shadow details? I know Photoshop can change one color to another without much trouble, but I've never seen anyone remove a background while keeping shadows.

Comment: check the different color channels and use them as an alpha channel. But I guess that is part of a different question and not related to the programming part :)

Answer (score 0):

A simple method I usually use in Appcelerator for tinting is to overlay your ImageView with a regular View but set the View's backgroundColor property with a transparency value in the form of ARGB like `backgroundColor: "#80FF0000"` as described in [this link](https://www.appcelerator.com/blog/2014/11/adding-transparent-background/).

However I'm not sure if this is the best method considering color accuracy since you're displaying this on shirt variations for a customer and I'm unaware of other approaches.

Comment: I did think about that. You're correct that color accuracy would be a problem because of how transparency affects things. The color will always be "off". I could never show rich colors because the amount of transparency needed to view the details underneath would wash them out.